# The difference between new VS code analysis options "Show compiler errors and warnings for:" and "Run background code analysis for:"

Tags: visual-studio, code-analysis, visual-studio-2022

I have just installed the latest update 17.3 for Visual Studio 2022 and noticed that code analysis settings changed. Now there are two options for code analysis scope:

- "Show compiler errors and warnings for:"
- "Run background code analysis for:"

Previously in VS version 17.2 there was only one "Run background code analysis for:" option. I didn't manage to find the description of the "Show compiler errors and warnings for:" setting in the release notes:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes

I also didn't manage to google anything about it in the internet.

I would like to know what the "Show compiler errors and warnings for:" setting does and what is the difference between it and "Run background code analysis for:"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing and playing with new code analysis settings I feel that I found out what "Show compiler errors and warnings for" and "Run background code analysis for" settings do now.
I will post my results as an answer. If you can add more details to my answer please do.

In short, the settings now divide code analysis diagnostics into two groups:

- Compiler diagnostics. Now you can configure the analysis scope for them with the **"Show compiler errors and warnings for:"** setting
- Diagnostics from custom Roslyn code analyzers. Now you can configure the analysis scope for them with the **"Run background code analysis for"** setting

The scopes are independent of each other. You can configure compiler diagnostics to be collected from the entire solution and custom diagnostic to be collected only from the current document. This way you can get build errors from the wider scope and save performance by running custom analyzers (which may require quite a lot of resources) on a narrower scope.

I tested this behavior by writing code that contains both syntax error and alert from the custom analyzer. To do this I installed xUnit unit test framework and xUnit analyzers provided with it. Then I wrote a simple unit test with syntax error and incorrect usage of xUnit:

[image: The incorrect test]

As you can see here, the test is marked with the `Fact` attribute but it contains parameters. Thus, it is reported by xUnit analyzers.
Additionally, there is a syntax error in the parameters list.

My current settings for code analysis are **Opened documents** for both analysis scopes. When I change **"Show compiler errors and warnings for:"** setting to **None** the compiler diagnostic on syntax error disappears:

[image: No compiler error]

The alert is displayed again after I change the setting back to **Opened documents**.
And when I change **"Run background code analysis for"** to **None** the xUnit analyzer diagnostic disappears:
[image: No custom alert]

So it seems to me, that now you can just configure code analysis separately for serious compiler checks and custom third party diagnostics.

Still, I would appreciate if someone shared the documentation for these settings with me.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure about the "Run background code analysis for" option, but I'm assuming it runs Roslyn code analysers (if you use these) in the background, rather than just on build.

From what I've experienced of the "Show compiler errors and warnings for", it seems to be a bit like a "live errors" window, showing build errors as you type, without actually having to build the solution.

E.g. if you make a breaking change to some code then you'll see the resulting errors start to populate in this window from across the solution (assuming you've selected the "entire solution" option). It can be quite slow and can take quite a bit of time for the b/g process to find and display the errors in the window. I guess this depends on solution size and PC performance.

Comment: The difference between two settings in your answer in not completely clear to me. 
From the answer it seems that the only difference is that the "Show compiler errors and warnings for" setting regulates only compiler checks that find errors that would break the build and "Run background code analysis for" regulates all diagnostics. So, now you can specify different analysis scopes for compiler diagnostics and all other Roslyn checks. Is that right?

Comment: From personal experience the "Show compiler errors..." setting seems to update the Error List window with "live" errors and warnings coming and going as you make changes to code, without having to build the solution first. As I say, I'm not 100% clear on the "Run background code analysis..." option, but I assume it works in a similar way but for displaying code analysis warnings (rather than build errors and warnings).

Comment: Well, I still don't understand what you see as the difference between "code analysis" alerts (which may include errors and warnings) and   "live" errors and warnings coming and going as you make changes to code".

Comment: As far as I can see, the new analysis options are completely unrelated to build. Both settings do live analysis without any build. Actually, I was right that they divide code analysis into two groups - compiler diagnostics and custom Roslyn diagnostics. The analysis scope for each group is regulated by its own setting.